# Assignment Problem with continuous decision variable

Tags: binary-variable, network-flow, assignment-problem, job-shop-scheduling, continuous-optimization

I have to solve a problem from industry where there are a number of machines which should be assigned to a number of tasks. The difference from the general assignment problem is tough, that the decision variable x is not a binary, it is a value between [0,1]. So that one machine can do 0.5(50%) of the task and another one can complete the task,does that make sense? I definied the problem like this:

[image]

When I program this problem in python with docplex, the solver is giving me only values of 1. Why there are no continuous values like 0.5 etc. Is there even a possibility that the mathematical optimal solution is a continuous value, or will this model always give binary results because there is a mathematical reason and maybe proof to that? So Does it even make sense to declare the decision variable as contionuous rather than binary?

Comment: *integrality property*

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/51) on this site, instead of uploading equations as images. Thank you.

Comment: Your second constraint is a bit odd. I would expect the machines to have individual capacity limits.

Comment: @Harun Gul, welcome to ORSE. Besides other useful comments and answers please be aware that, the problem you mentioned is classified as mixed-integer programming, but still there are the cases you can formulate your problem as a linear program to get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there even a possibility that the mathematical optimal solution is
> a continuous value

I would say it depends on the parameterization, i.e., the values of c and t and b in your problem. From your description, it seems entirely possible to have a parameterization that leads to an optimal solution with integer values.
Generally, it is a good practise to start with a tiny example which you can fully solve and understand manually

I would suggest to test your implementation with a minimal example which you construct in a way that you know the optimal solution is fractional. Here is a suggestion:

Lets say there is just one task, so $J = \{1\}$ and two machines $I = \{1,2\}$
You have the following constraint:

$$4x_1 + 2x_2 \leq 3$$
I am omitting the task index here. Now, $t_1$ is larger than $b$, so $x_1=1$ would be an infeasible solution. Finally, you can prevent $x_2=1$ from becoming optimal by selecting objective coefficients that favor $x_1$, e.g., $c_2=5$ and $c_1=1$. Independent of the values for the $c_i$,as long as the second machine is more expensive than the first, the optimal solution should be $x_1=x_2=0.5$ because you still have the constraint that the one task has to be completely fulfilled, so

$$x_1 + x_2 =1$$
still has to be fulfilled.

Hope this helps figuring out what's going on!